# Getting assembly reference error using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Hi i am getting the following error while using c# code in visual studio 2010.

```
The type or namespace name 'Controller' does not exist in the namespace 'Demo4' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    C:\Documents and Settings\Subhrajyoti\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Demo4\Demo4.Tests\Controllers\MapsControllerTest.cs  8   13  Demo4.Tests
```

The following is my code.

> MapsControllerTest.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Demo4;
using Demo4.Controller;
namespace Demo4.Tests.Controllers
{
    class MapsControllerTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void ViewMaps()
        {
            // Arrange
            MapsController controller = new MapsController();

            // Act
            ViewResult result = controller.ViewMaps() as ViewResult;

            // Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        }

    }
}
```

Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: It should be Controllers, please chack